Is it possible to ask on launch for job templates while calling them from a workflow template in Ansible Automation Platform?
I have a job template that has prompt on launch fields and they are prompting when I launch them individually. However, when I call it from a workflow template it is not asking while workflow template is launching. Workflow template asks for prompt answers for that job template while I am creating it and it continues with default selections not asking on launch.
Do you know any solution?
I was expecting job template to prompt for parameters when workflow template is launching and calling it.
